# Descobrir endereço do usuario pelo IP pra exibir um modal

Tags: php, javascript

Boa tarde, gostaria de pegar os valores da geolocalização do usuario e exibir um model caso ele esteja em determinada localização, eu consigo pegar os valores de coordenadas, mas como faço pra passar pro php esses valores que estão no javascript?

```
<div> 
    <p id="demo">Clique no botão para receber sua localização em Latitude e Longitude:</p>
    <button onclick="getLocation()">Clique Aqui</button>
    <script>
        var x=document.getElementById("demo");
        function getLocation()
        {
            if (navigator.geolocation)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            }
            else{x.innerHTML="O seu navegador não suporta Geolocalização.";}
        }
        function showPosition(position)
        {
            x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
                "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: usando o tal do ajax

Comment: vou tentar, obrigado

Comment: Faça uma requisição GET ou POST para o seu php